# Recover location information from trace using bfd

Tags: c, linux, stack-trace, debug-symbols, bfd

I am using the `dladdr` from `libld` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr) to get a trace of the function calls. Here it is minimal example with a single traced element:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h> // link with -ldl -rdynamic a

void f(){
    void **frame = static_cast<void **>(__builtin_frame_address(0));
    void **bp = static_cast<void **>(*frame);
    void *ip = frame[1];
    Dl_info info;
    dladdr(ip, &info);
    std::cout << info.dli_sname << " " << info.dli_fname << " " << info.dli_saddr << std::endl;

    ip = bp[1];
    bp = static_cast<void**>(bp[0]);
    dladdr(ip, &info);
    std::cout << info.dli_sname << " " << info.dli_fname << " " << info.dli_saddr << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    f();
}
```

which outputs:

```
  main ./a.out 0x402800
__libc_start_main /lib64/libc.so.6 0x7febf6bf2610
```

that is, `Dl_info` has the traced function name, the compiled file where it belongs and some **address** (`0x7f...`) described in the man page as "Exact address of symbol named".

This **address** has information of the source file location (from where the function has been called). In fact with the help of some utility I can get that information:

```
$ addr2line -e a.out
/home/user/test.cpp:34
```

(give the exact line where `main` is defined in source file). And this works as long as the program was compiled with the `-g` option.

**Now what I want is to extract this information programmaticaly. Supposedly, this is possible with the BFD library.**

This is my attempt, based on BFD examples found for example here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/X11libs/X11libs-40.2/cairo/cairo-1.8.6/util/backtrace-symbols.c

1) first I have to define a function `find_addr_sect` that will be called by `bfd_map_over_sections` (through a pointer) later.

```
static void find_addr_sect(bfd *abfd, asection *section, void *obj){


    bfd_data *data = (bfd_data *)obj;
    bfd_vma vma;
    bfd_size_type size;

    if (data->found)
        return;

    if (!(bfd_get_section_vma(abfd, section)))
        return;

    vma = bfd_get_section_vma(abfd, section);
    if (data->pc < vma)
        return;

    size = bfd_get_section_size(section);
    if (data->pc >= vma + size)
        return;

    data->found = bfd_find_nearest_line(abfd, section, syms,
                        data->pc - vma,
                        &data->filename,
                        &data->function,
                        &data->line);

}
```

2) I put the code directing inside the function (this replaces the function `void f()` above.

```
void f(){

    void **frame = static_cast<void **>(__builtin_frame_address(0));
    void **bp = static_cast<void **>(*frame);
    void *ip = frame[1];
    Dl_info info;
    dladdr(ip, &info);
    std::cout << info.dli_sname << " " << info.dli_fname << " " << info.dli_saddr << std::endl;
////////////////////
    // this will try to find the location of main (first in the stack)
    bfd *abfd = bfd_openr(info.dli_fname, NULL); assert(abfd); // the executable file is opened successfully
//  bfd_data data;
    bfd_map_over_sections(abfd, find_addr_sect, nullptr); // !! doesn't call `find_addr_sect` at all.


///////////////////
    ip = bp[1];
    bp = static_cast<void**>(bp[0]);

    dladdr(ip, &info);
    std::cout << info.dli_sname << " " << info.dli_fname << " " << info.dli_saddr << std::endl;

}
```

Sadly, I am stuck here because the `bfd_map_over_sections` call doesn't do anything. I am using `bfd_map_over_sections` in the wrong way, why?

Sorry for using C++, in this is a C question. It shortens most of my code and I am more used to it.

---

**EDIT:** I added this lines and I can confirm that one clue of the problem is that the number of sections is zero.

```
unsigned int numSections = -1;
numSections =  bfd_count_sections(abfd);
std::cout << "num sections " << numSections << std::endl; // gives "0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for more examples, it seems that I was missing two things, calling the function `bfd_check_format` after opening and also populating and passing the address information in the `bfd_data` structure.

```
...
    bfd *abfd = bfd_openr(info.dli_fname, NULL); assert(abfd);
//  char **matching;
//  bfd_data data;// = (bfd_data *)obj;

    if (!bfd_check_format (abfd, bfd_object)){
        bfd_close (abfd);       assert(0);
    }
...
```

later `bfd_data` variable is used as input and output of the `find_addr_sect`. Therefore

```
...
bfd_data data;// = (bfd_data *)obj;
data.pc = (bfd_hostptr_t)info.dli_saddr;
data.found = FALSE;
bfd_map_over_sections(abfd, find_addr_sect, &data);
...
```

And now it works.